# Why is conditional clause comparing dataframe columns causing error even though conditional clause is boolean in nature?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, if-statement, dataframe

I am trying to build logic that compares two columns in a dataframe after some logic has been verified.

Here is my code, it is pulling historical rates for cryptocurrency data from gdax.com. The test condition I am applying is 'if df.column 4 is greater than sum of df.column4 and df.column3 then buy 10% of account'

```
import GDAX
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

public_client = GDAX.PublicClient()
ticker_call = public_client.getProductHistoricRates(product='LTC-USD')

df = pd.DataFrame(ticker_call)


df['account']=100



if df[4] > df[3] + df[4]:
    df['account_new'] = df['account']-df['account'] *.10
    print df
```

I am getting the error `'ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'` for the if statement, what I dont understand is why? when I run each of the lines in the if statement individually they work. How can I fix this issue?

Why and how do I use a.bool() instead of an if statement?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[4] > df[3] + df[4]
```

(that actually is equivalent to `df[3] < 0`) is a pandas.Series of boolean values. When do you want to enter the `if` statement? When all values are `True`? then you should use `all()`. When any of them is `True`? Then you should use `any()`.

If instead you want to execute that function for any row when the condition is `True`, you should do something like

```
condition = df[4] > df[3] + df[4]
true_df = df[condition]
true_df["account_new"] = true_df['account']-true_df['account'] *.10
```

but now the columns `"account_new"` exists only in `true_df`, and not in `df`.

With something like

```
df["account_new"] = true_df["account_new"]
```

now also `df` has the column `"account_new"`, but in the lines where `condition` is false you have nans...

Comment: Hey @PietroTortella, that worked beautifully and you understood correct when all values are true is when I want to enter the if statement. 

Is it better to create conditional statements in pandas without the if statement and more so the way you made it?

Comment: It depends on the use you want to do... in your case doing `if all(condition):` is fine, in some other cases you'll need to perform an operation on the rows of a dataframe satisfying a condition, and you'll use the second strategy...

Comment: can chain multiple if-else statements under one all() clause? for example if all(condition):
   elseif(condtion):